# Reaching Spring's tx:advice from pure AspectJ

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I enabled LTW for my Spring application and as long as the advised bean in question is free of Spring's AOP features, the classes are woven properly - that is, in-method bytecode modification rather than proxies.

However, once I add `tx:annotation-driven` and `@Transactional` to that bean, all methods, even those having nothing to do with Spring features, that previously were woven with proper bytecode, now all get called via JDK proxy.

Which probably means I have to let go of `tx:annotation-driven` and configure AspectJ to use Spring's `tx:advice` for methods annotated with Spring's `@Transactional`.

But how do I access Spring beans from AspectJ configuration?

Comment: And why not simply let AspectJ drive your transactions? This is supported out-of-the-box... `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />` should be all you need (this registers an Aspect which handles `@Transactional`).

Comment: @m-deinum Not all places where I need transactions have `@Transactional`, and not all `@Transactional` places should be transactional. Heaps of old production code.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to add AspectJ compiler to the build toolchain and implement the `AbstractTransactionAspect.aj` aspect and on Spring startup call `TheImplementedAspect.aspectOf().setTransactionManager()`.